# Any Intel 8048 assembly resources out there?

Tags: resources, intel, manual, assembly

Are there any out there? I'm looking at developing something for a retro console, and can't seem to find any resources. I have found an assembler and disassembler package, asm48, however.

I've seen listings for a book called the "Intel MCS-48 Programming Manual" or something similar, but I can't actually find the BOOK.

Similarly, I've only found one example of code, a Magnavox Odyssey 2 homebrew game that was released under the GPL, called "Kill the Attacking Aliens", and it is VERY well commented, but it would still be nice to have backup resources that were meant for teaching the subject.

Thanks in advance guys.

EDIT: I seem to have found one resource, in the form of the "MCS-48 Microcomputer User's Manual", which can be found here ( www.sharpmz.org/download/8048.pdf ), and has the entire instruction set listed. I might be able to work off of this. However, if anyone else has any other resources, I'm still interested in hearing. :)

Comment: That was 35 years ago.  You'll have to visit a museum.

Comment: Hans Passant is quite right, things like that are not easy to find. You may try asking in a library of some IT/CS university. I would strongly suggest asking at electronics.stackexchange.com . You have a much better chance of getting an answer there because back then, electronics engineering and computers were quite closer to each other than today.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of information for hardware and software development of MCS-48 systems was gathered in
Grokking the MCS-48 System
Version 3.3, October 2007
which is available under "http://home.mnet-online.de/al/mcs-48/mcs-48.pdf". 
For language reference see "http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/intel/8048/9800255D_MCS-48_and_UPI-41_Assembly_Language_Reference_Manual_Dec78.pdf".
Good luck.